# HighCharts Bubble graph JSON as data source

Tags: javascript, json, charts, highcharts

I am stuck in a problem where bubble chart series is not plotting - inspite of doing it according to HighCharts example tutorial. 
There is no error on browser console as well making it really difficult for me to figure out.

Following is the data received from AJAX onSuccess response:

```
d:"[{"id":"3","name":"Australia","x":"24.1","y":"19.9","z":"3.5"},{"id":"1","name":"England (STA)","x":"23.8","y":"20.5","z":"2.6"},{"id":"5","name":"Germany","x":"22.8","y":"20.9","z":"2.3"},{"id":"2","name":"Spain","x":"17.8","y":"22.2","z":"1.4"}]"
```

Below is full code where I binded it to HighCharts:

```
function ShowMaturityGraph() {
        var params = {};
        params.countryIDList = "1,2,3,5";
        params.xAxis = "1";
        params.yAxis = "2";
        params.bubbleSize = "6";

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "default.aspx/GetMaturityValues",
            data: JSON.stringify(params),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                visitorData(response.d);
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response.d);
            }
        });
    }
    function visitorData(data) {
        alert(data);
        Highcharts.chart('container', {

            chart: {
                type: 'bubble',
                plotBorderWidth: 1,
                zoomType: 'xy'
            },

            legend: {
                enabled: false
            },

            title: {
                text: 'Maturity Values'
            },

            subtitle: {
                text: ''
            },

            xAxis: {
                gridLineWidth: 1,
                title: {
                    text: ''
                },
                labels: {
                    format: ''
                },
                plotLines: [{
                    color: 'black',
                    dashStyle: 'dot',
                    width: 2,
                    value: 65,
                    label: {
                        rotation: 0,
                        y: 15,
                        style: {
                            fontStyle: 'italic'
                        },
                        text: ''
                    },
                    zIndex: 3
                }]
            },

            yAxis: {
                startOnTick: false,
                endOnTick: false,
                title: {
                    text: ''
                },
                labels: {
                    format: ''
                },
                maxPadding: 0.2,
                plotLines: [{
                    color: 'black',
                    dashStyle: 'dot',
                    width: 2,
                    value: 50,
                    label: {
                        align: 'right',
                        style: {
                            fontStyle: 'italic'
                        },
                        text: '',
                        x: -10
                    },
                    zIndex: 3
                }]
            },


            plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        //format: '{point.name}'
                    }
                }
            },

            series: $.parseJSON(data),

        });
    }
```

Comment: which highchart example you are using for this?

Comment: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/bubble
Instead of hardcoded series, assigned the object.

Comment: hight chart expect data in numbers, float values etc, in yours its string.

Comment: @Rohit  series: [{ data : [<array>] }] whereas you are passing array in series also parsevalues as int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**How about something like that** i am using your data. You change it as you pleased. its high chart example with data provided above in the question.

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {

  chart: {
    type: 'bubble',
    plotBorderWidth: 1,
    zoomType: 'xy'
  },

  legend: {
    enabled: false
  },

  title: {
    text: 'Sugar and fat intake per country'
  },

  subtitle: {
    text: 'Source: <a href="http://www.euromonitor.com/">Euromonitor</a> and <a href="https://data.oecd.org/">OECD</a>'
  },

  xAxis: {
    gridLineWidth: 1,
    title: {
      text: 'Daily fat intake'
    },
    labels: {
      format: '{value} gr'
    },
    plotLines: [{
      color: 'black',
      dashStyle: 'dot',
      width: 2,
      value: 65,
      label: {
        rotation: 0,
        y: 15,
        style: {
          fontStyle: 'italic'
        },
        text: 'Safe fat intake 65g/day'
      },
      zIndex: 3
    }]
  },

  yAxis: {
    startOnTick: false,
    endOnTick: false,
    title: {
      text: 'Daily sugar intake'
    },
    labels: {
      format: '{value} gr'
    },
    maxPadding: 0.2,
    plotLines: [{
      color: 'black',
      dashStyle: 'dot',
      width: 2,
      value: 50,
      label: {
        align: 'right',
        style: {
          fontStyle: 'italic'
        },
        text: 'Safe sugar intake 50g/day',
        x: -10
      },
      zIndex: 3
    }]
  },

  tooltip: {
    useHTML: true,
    headerFormat: '<table>',
    pointFormat: '<tr><th colspan="2"><h3>{point.country}</h3></th></tr>' +
      '<tr><th>Fat intake:</th><td>{point.x}g</td></tr>' +
      '<tr><th>Sugar intake:</th><td>{point.y}g</td></tr>' +
      '<tr><th>Obesity (adults):</th><td>{point.z}%</td></tr>',
    footerFormat: '</table>',
    followPointer: true
  },

  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        format: '{point.name}'
      }
    }
  },

  series: [{
    data: [{
      "id": "3",
      "name": "Australia",
      "x": 24.1,
      "y": 19.9,
      "z": 3.5
    }, {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "England (STA)",
      "x": 23.8,
      "y": 20.5,
      "z": 2.6
    }, {
      "id": "5",
      "name": "Germany",
      "x": 22.8,
      "y": 20.9,
      "z": 2.3
    }, {
      "id": "2",
      "name": "Spain",
      "x": 17.8,
      "y": 22.2,
      "z": 1.4
    }]
  }]

});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px; min-width: 310px; max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

hope that helps.